# php mysqli stored procedure realize insert or update done successfully

Tags: php, android, stored-procedures, mysqli

I am useing php for my android application websevice, I use mysqli stored procedure for safe insert in web database.
my code :

```
$query = "UPDATE tbl_users SET Coins = ? WHERE Username = ?";
    if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare(self::$con, $query)) {
        $stmt->bind_param("ss", $coin, $username);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }else{
        die("{OpState:[{opstate:ERROR_Config}]}");
    }
```

How Can I undrestand the update done than I can send success message to my android client?
I have the same question for INSERT opration, how can I get the id of row that my record inserted in , in stored procedure?

Comment: Use `mysqli_affected_rows` for that. It return _Returns the number of rows affected by the last INSERT, UPDATE, REPLACE or DELETE query._ Use `if(mysqli_affected_rows($con)>0){echo "success"}else{echo "error"}`

Comment: Just after your query execute!!

Comment: thank you, done well. and how can I get the row id that my INSERT opration take place in?